# Floating Action button is not showing properly

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, floating-action-button

The **Floating Action Button** is not showing properly in the Android Studio layout editor but it shows properly in-app.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Fragments.Book_Fragment">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:src="@drawable/fav_selector"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.047" />
```

It seems like this in layout editor of the android studio:

[Floting Action Button Here Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q4hpW.png)

Comment: Can u provide complete XML code?

Comment: This error is only in Layout Editor of Android studio